# How to show RecyclerView after a new activity is created, Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

When my Home fragment uses regular buttons through intent to go to a new class. On the new class when I try to use `RecylerVie` and Firebase to show data, the data does not appear and the app crashes.

On my Firebase the nodes go from  project --> to DataHome --> Home1. 
Home 1 has the attributes description,directions, ingredients, image, title

DataHome also has other nodes named Home2, etc. But in this case I'm only trying to show data from Home1 on this class.

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEHEi.jpg)

The logcat says Fatal Exception Main: Process: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.tmrecipes.Model.DataHome

This is the class:

```
public class BeefSamosa extends AppCompatActivity {


    FirebaseDatabase mHomeFireBaseDatabase;
    RecyclerView myhomeview;
    private DatabaseReference DataHomeRef;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beef_samosa);
        //Back Button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Beef Samosa");


        //Recycler View
        myhomeview = findViewById(R.id.beefview);
        myhomeview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set layout as LinearLayout
        myhomeview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        //send query to firebase database
        mHomeFireBaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DataHomeRef = mHomeFireBaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DataHome").child("Home1");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            //ends the activity
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("DataHome")
                .child("Home1");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataHome> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataHome>()
                        .setQuery(DataHomeRef, DataHome.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataHome,DataHomeViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataHome, DataHomeViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public DataHomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewtype) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_home_deatil, parent, false);

                return new DataHomeViewHolder(view);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHomeViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataHome model) {
                    holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getImage(), model.getDescription() , model.getIngredients(), model.getDirections());
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        myhomeview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    //DataHomeViewHolder class

    public static class DataHomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        View mview;


        public DataHomeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview = itemView;



        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx, String title, String image, String description, String ingredients , String directions) {

            //Views
            TextView mHomeTitle = mview.findViewById(R.id.titlewords);
            ImageView mHomeImage = mview.findViewById(R.id.loading_pic);
            TextView mDescriptionTitle = mview.findViewById(R.id.descriptionwords);
            TextView mIngredientsTitle = mview.findViewById(R.id.ingredientwords);
            TextView mDirectionsTitle = mview.findViewById(R.id.directionwords);

            //Set data to views
            mHomeTitle.setText(title);
            mDescriptionTitle.setText(description);
            mIngredientsTitle.setText(ingredients);
            mDirectionsTitle.setText(directions);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(mHomeImage);

        }


    }
}
```

My model class is:

```
 public class DataHome {

        public String title ,image, description, ingredients, directions;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getIngredients() {
            return ingredients;
        }

        public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
            this.ingredients = ingredients;
        }

        public String getDirections() {
            return directions;
        }

        public void setDirections(String directions) {
            this.directions = directions;
        }

        public DataHome(String title, String image, String description, String ingredients, String directions){
            this.title =title;
            this.image = image;
            this.description = description;
                this.ingredients = ingredients;
                this.directions=directions;
            }

    }
```

Edit: The changed class is:

public class BeefSamosa extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beef_samosa);
    //Back Button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Beef Samosa");


    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.beef_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = rootRef.child("DataHome");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataHome> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataHome>()
            .setQuery(query, DataHome.class)
            .build();


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataHome, DataHomeViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHomeViewHolder dataHomeViewHolder, int position, @NonNull DataHome dataHome) {
            dataHomeViewHolder.setDataHome(dataHome);
        }

        @Override
        public DataHomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homedetail, parent, false);

            return new DataHomeViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter!= null) {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        //ends the activity
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





//DataHomeViewHolder class

private class DataHomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView imagetoo, titletext, description, ingredients, directions;


    DataHomeViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        imagetoo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagetoo);
        titletext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        ingredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);
        directions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.directions);
    }


    void setDataHome(DataHome DataHome) {
        String imageto = DataHome.getImage();
        imagetoo.setText(imageto);
        String titleto = DataHome.getTitle();
        titletext.setText(titleto);
        String descriptionto = DataHome.getDescription();
        description.setText(descriptionto);
        String ingredientsto = DataHome.getIngredients();
        ingredients.setText(ingredientsto);
        String directionsto = DataHome.getDirections();
        directions.setText(directionsto);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code? Have you tried to call `myhomeview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);` before `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();`?

Comment: When I use the code; when I click the button on my home fragment to take me to the new page (the new page is the class I put in the question ), the new page displays nothing and the app crashes. When I try to call myhomeview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); before it still doesn't display anything and crashes.

Comment: The logcat says Fatal Exception Main: Process: 
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.tmrecipes.Model.DataHome           
        at  com.google.firebase.database.core.utilitiescoding.ToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
    ... etc.

Comment: Please also add your database structure.

Comment: I added the image above in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
 Fatal Exception Main: Process: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.tmrecipes.Model.DataHome
```

Because the children under `Home1` node are strings and not `DataHome` objects. To solve this, you need to pass to your `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object a query that points to a node where `DataHome` objects exist. So please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("DataHome")
            .child("Home1");
```

to

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("DataHome");
```

See, I have removed the call to `.child("Home1")` because this is producing the error. This change will help you display all `DataHome` objects that exist within the all `DataHome` node.

If you want to display only the details of `Home1` for example, there is no need to use the Firebase-UI library, you can simply get the value of all properties and display them in a list as explained in my answer from this post:

- [How can I retrieve data from Firebase to my adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)

Comment: Alright changing the query didn't fix it right way, but I'll try doing what you explained in  the other post now.

Comment: The first solution is to display `DataHome` objects and the other can help you display properties of single object. Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: I changed the class but I'm still getting an error message. I updated the question at the bottom, with the changed class shown.

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.tmrecipes.DataHome does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

Comment: I was just missing the empty constructor in the DataHome class. I got it now thank you for helping me out and putting time in to help other people all the time.